# std::this_thread::sleep_for sleeps shorter than expected in VS2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Let's have the following piece of code, that simply measures the duration of `std::this_thread::sleep_for` called with 20ms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(20));
        auto end = steady_clock::now();
        duration<double, milli> elapsed = end - start;
        cout << "Waited " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

When run as compiled with toolset v120 (VS2013's) I get results as expected, i.e.:

```
Waited 20.0026 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0026 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0026 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0025 ms
Waited 20.0026 ms
```

but when run with VS2015's toolset v140, results are somewhat surprising and don't respect the promise from both [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920528%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) `sleep_for` descriptions (that `sleep_for` blocks the execution of the current thread for **at least** the specified `sleep_duration`). They are as following:

```
Waited 19.7793 ms
Waited 19.9415 ms
Waited 19.6056 ms
Waited 19.9687 ms
Waited 19.608 ms
Waited 19.589 ms
Waited 20.5435 ms
Waited 19.5669 ms
Waited 19.6802 ms
Waited 19.5381 ms
```

How its possible and how can I make VS2015's `sleep_for` to sleep at least as long as expected?

Regards, Dawid

**EDIT:**

As requested those are my settings and OS details:
**OS**:

- Windows 7 Professional 64bit
- Visual Studios: 2010 Ultimate, 2013 Community, 2015 Professional with Update 1

**Compiler settings**:

- default settings for Win32 Console Application,
- any of Debug and Release configurations,
- any of x86 and x64 target platform architectures

Comment: I generally use `sleep_until()` in a loop in case of early wake up. I think early wake up is not supposed to happen but on GCC Linux, at least, early wake up seems to happen whenever the process receives a signal (obviously not your problem here).

Comment: I don't see the same results locally or e.g. on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual (it's also using VS2015). Consider adding more info about your exact compiler settings, target architecture, host OS, machine specs etc.

Comment: @Yirkha: I've added more details about my conditions in the description. As for your results - it is going to look like hunting little differences in my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sleep_for()` method implementation in VS2015 already contains a loop around the [`Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) system call, so any spurious wakeups will not affect it - see `_Thrd_sleep()` in `VC\crt\src\stl\cthread.c`.

---

The cause of your problems is most probably the fact that `sleep_for()`, and `sleep_until()` it calls inside, are using `chrono::system_clock` to calculate the time to wait, but you are measuring the period using `chrono::steady_clock`.

Both timers might have the same precision, but not necessarily the same accuracy. Then it can happen that the `system_clock` is lagging a little bit, while `steady_clock` is already a few μs ahead, and the wait calculated using `system_clock` is actually shorter than requested.

---

In this exact case, `steady_clock` is implemented using [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx) (see `VC\include\chrono`, search for `struct steady_clock`), so it will be very accurate and precise, as that's the preferred Windows API to use for exact time measurements.

`system_clock` is implemented using [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895.aspx) (see `VC\include\chrono`, search for `struct system_clock`), which promises *"the highest possible level of precision (<1us)"* also. Alas, as the MSDN page says, this API is supported only from Windows 8 up and you are stuck with the older [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397.aspx) with just ms precision on your Windows 7 machine. And that is most probably the result of your measurement errors.

---

Depending on your exact use case, you might deal with this in different ways of course. I'd consider just ignoring the small error, as suspending the thread and waiting for the scheduler to wake it up will not be very accurate anyway.

Comment: It looks like the reason in deed comes from differences in clocks used by `sleep_for` and my measurement method. To check that I've temporarily changed measuring clock to `system_clock` and results are just as expected. However it is quite suspicious since you haven't reproduced this effect locally which makes me think that your `sleep_for` uses `steady_clock`. If so, if it depends from OS conditions, is there any way to make `sleep_for` use `steady_clock`?

Comment: This is implemented internally in the CRT, not even through `chrono` interfaces, so you would have to rebuild it - so no. Windows upgrade >=8 would solve everything, or you could just add some tiny amount of duration on the affected platforms (to make the "waits for >=X" requirement always true).

Answer (score 2):

While standard says that an implementation *should* use a `steady_clock` for the `*_for` timing functions, that is not required. And if a non-steady clock is used, then adjustments in the clock can result in the sleep time falling short. In such case the timing functions *might not provide useful functionality* as noted by the standard.

However, your results show consistent short falling, which I think could indicate behaviour that doesn't conform to the standard.

You can work around such behaviour by measuring the time yourself using the clock of your own choice and sleeping in a loop until the target time has passed.